# Confusion about timezone when inserting record to DB using gorm?

Tags: go, timezone, go-gorm

For example, if my application layer is using timezone `UTC +07:00` and my DB is having timezone `UTC +00:00`. As I understand, when I write a record `2020-02-10 16:16:16 +07:00` from the application layer to DB, Gorm will write `2020-02-10 16:16:16` to DB and remove the `+07:00` part.

When I read the record back to the application layer, it will read `2020-02-10 16:16:16` and attach `+07:00` part to the time.

Is this the correct behavior of Gorm? I have search through the internet but do not have enough information to back my understanding.

Comment: *"I have search through the internet but do not have enough information to back my understand."* Why don't you try it and see for yourself whether the inserted and the read `time.Time` values are [`.Equal`](https://golang.org/pkg/time/#Time.Equal) or not?

Comment: Whether or not the UTC offset is stored depends on the database. Postgres has both timestamp and timestamptz types, for instance.

Comment: @Peter how about mysql?